# Let $w$ be a primitve third root of unity. Find the units of $A=\{a+bw, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: ring-theory, roots-of-unity

What I have so far: if $x \in \mathbb{C}$, then $N(x)=\bar{x}x$ is multiplicative ($N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$). So $N$ restricted to $A$ is also multiplicative.

if $a+bw \in A$, then it's easy to see that $N(a+bi)=(a+bw)(a+b\bar{w})= (...) = a^2-ab+b^2$ (I'm using that $\bar{w}=w^2$ and that $w+w^2+1=0$)

If $x$ is a unit of $A$, $\exists\ y$ which satisfies $xy=1 \Rightarrow N(xy)=N(x)N(y) = 1$. It must be that, if $x=a+bw$ , $|a^2-ab+b^2| = 1$.

$a^2-ab+b^2=(a-b)^2 + ab$, so if $(a-b)^2=0$ then $a=b$, then $a^2 = 1$, so we have $a=b=\pm 1$. It's easy to find x^-1 in this case (and in other similar ones, where a=0, for example).

My problem is then we have $(a-b)^2 >0$. I'm stuck. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Your way can be pushed through. I prefer to use
$$2(a^2-ab+b^2)=(a-b)^2+a^2+b^2.$$
So exactly two of $a$, $b$, and $a-b$ are equal to $\pm 1$ and the other is equal to $0$. Now the solutions should not be hard to find.

Comment: @Nicolas, in that case, I suppose that what you are saying is $\pm 2 = (a-b)^2+a^2+b^2$, right? Awesome!

Comment: Not $\pm 2$, just $2$, the right-hand side is a sum of squares, therefore always non-negative. It is one of several ways of showing that $a^2-ab+b^2$ is always $\ge 0$.

Comment: Using $N()$, I thought it should be easy to prove that it's euclidean. I know the standard way to prove it...but if $(a+bi)/(c+di) = x+yi$, I should be able to find a $z=e+fi \in A$ near enough of $x+yi$... And I can't. $f$ is the closest integer to $\frac{x-e}{cos (\alpha)}$. Do you have any hints? :)

Comment: @Nicolas, you are right about the minus, obviously. When I sat down that was the first thing I noted. Thanks!

Comment: De nada.$\,\,\,\,\,$

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique is to complete the square as if you are solving the very basic quadratic equation all over again:

$4 = 4(a^2-ab+b^2) = (2a-b)^2 + 3b^2$.